# How to help seedlings recover from tip burn

Tags: plant-health, diseases, seedlings, light

I germinated some seeds and I had the seedlings under a two new 40w LED grow light for a few weeks. I'm used to keeping florescent lights very close to the plants, but apparently this LED light is more powerful. The tips of the leaves got yellow and crispy I turned off one of the lights and raised it up to 8+ inches above the leaves. It seems like it may be too late for some of my unfortunate toasted plants, but is there anything else I can do to help the others recover? I'm watering weekly with a mild organic kelp fertilizer.

Answer (score 1):

Back off the fertilizer. Adding a fertilizer to plant that is not in a strong growth state will also cause leaf burn. Reduce the amount of water. If the plants not growing, the water just stays in the pot and the rots will rot. Secondly, it seems like the plants are indoors? Definitely place it in a location with a little more circulation. Or place it near a window where it gets filtered sunlight.